# 500 error: Cast to ObjectId failed for value

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I get the error from the server.

> "{"message":{"message":"Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"authors\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Comment\"","name":"CastError","stringValue":"\"authors\"","kind":"ObjectId","value":"authors","path":"_id"}}"

I have the model:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var commentSchema = new Schema({
  author: String,
  title: String,
  text: String,
  favorite: Number
});

var Comment = mongoose.model("Comment", commentSchema);

module.exports = Comment;
```

From the client which written by Angular 2 I send the request using the method:

```
getAuthors() {
         return this.http.get(this.appConfig.urlServer + "/comment/authors")
             .map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
```

I have next route:

```
var express = require("express");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Comment = require("../models/comment");
var router = express.Router();

router.get("/comment/authors", getAuthorsOfComments);

module.exports = router;

function getAuthorsOfComments(req, res) {
    Comment.find({}, 'author', function(err, authors) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).json({
        message: err
      })
    }

    if (authors) {
      res.status(200).json({
        authors: authors
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Please, help me. I don't know why I get error.

**UPDATE 1.**

Entries from the Comment collection.
First entry:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59269000483977cefe7961e0"),
    "author" : "test",
    "title" : "title of text",
    "text" : "Big text",
    "favorite" : 1
}
```

Second entry:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5926901b483977cefe7961f2"),
    "author" : "test2",
    "title" : "title of text",
    "text" : "Big text",
    "favorite" : 5
}
```

Comment: Could you post some entries from the Comment collection?

Comment: Yes, I could. I updated my post.

Comment: are you sure, you are using the exact code you posted?  Your code looks just fine and should work without any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem is with your query method, you are not querying the database properly and not calling the callback function appropriately. I will rewrite your query code.

```
function getAuthorsOfComments(req, res) {
    Comment.find({}, {author: 1}).then( function(err, authors) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).json({
        message: err
      })
    }

    if (authors) {
      res.status(200).json({
        authors: authors
      })
    }
  })
}
```

*{author: 1}* tells the *mongoDB* to just return the author. If you put 0 instead of 1, *mongoDB* will return all the fields but not author.

Comment: i dont see any problem with the OP's query. his query is perfectly fine.

Comment: I fount the reason of the error. I wrote the uncorrect urls in other methods of the route, so I didn't execute the query to the database.